How to pass multiple images as @RequestPart in Spring feign client?
I am trying to pass multiple files (images) using feign client. However, when I am using @RequestPart annotation for list or array of MultipartFile, I am getting an error. For a single MultipartFile it works fine.
Feign client method:
    
    @ApiResponses(value = { @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "OK", response = FileInfo.class) })
    @PostMapping(
            value = "/upload-multi-files",
            produces = { "application/json" },
            consumes = { "multipart/form-data" }
    )
    ResponseEntity<FileInfo> uploadMultiFiles(@NotNull @Valid @RequestPart(value = "images", required = true) List<MultipartFile> images);

When I invoke it from the code, I am getting a following error:
feign.codec.EncodeException: Could not write request: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [java.util.ArrayList] and content type [multipart/form-data]
    at org.springframework.cloud.openfeign.support.SpringEncoder.encode(SpringEncoder.java:143) ~[spring-cloud-openfeign-core-2.1.0.RELEASE.jar:2.1.0.RELEASE]
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$BuildEncodedTemplateFromArgs.resolve(ReflectiveFeign.java:372) ~[feign-core-10.1.0.jar:?]
    at feign.ReflectiveFeign$BuildTemplateByResolvingArgs.create(ReflectiveFeign.java:224) ~[feign-core-10.1.0.jar:?]
    ...

How can I make it work with either list or array?

I think this could help you: feign form

Use this param type "MultipartFile[]" replace "List"

As I said, for array there is a similar error: no suitable HttpMessageConverter found for request type [[Lorg.springframework.web.multipart.MultipartFile;] and content type [multipart/form-data].

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
